# Recorded macro to unhide columns in Google sheets will not run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

The recorded macro looks like this:

```
 function Unhide() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('A:P').activate();
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().showColumns(0, 16);
    };
```

When trying to execute the macro it stops and shows the following error message:

> Exception: Those columns are out of bounds

Comment: How many columns do you have in your sheet ?

Answer (score 2):

Try switching your starting index of [showColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showColumns(Integer,Integer)) to 1.

```
function Unhide() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:P').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().showColumns(1, 16);
};
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot!  Maybe column 0 does not exist!

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. It doesn't either exist row 0. All of them start from 1 onwards.